# Katalon UI recorder fails to run for date and radio buttons

Tags: date, radio-button, automated-tests, katalon-studio, katalon-recorder

I'm new to Katalon Studio.

I did UI web (chrome) recording for my application which has 14 entries.

When i run the test it lauches the browser and continues until it fails at the date selection object.

I deleted the date object and ran again but then it failed at a radio button.

I am using Katalon Suite version 6.1.5

Also, please suggest if I can use another tool for automated testing that simply runs this test without the need of workarounds for date or radio buttons ?

Comment: You should first click the "Abholdatum" element and then *wait* for the date-select element to be clickable. Are you doing something like this?

Answer (score 0):

You should detect elements by `xpath` or set correct `xpath` (You can get xpath of object with your browser.) for recorded elements under `Object Repository`. Please check this article: https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/tutorials/detect_elements_xpath.html#issue-in-identifying-nested-elements

**EDIT**
You can use these identifiers to identify object in calendar.
[image: calendar object]

Comment: I tried to set relative xpath but it still fails. I may wish to post a fresh thread for this issue.

Comment: I tried relative xpath but it still fails. I may post a fresh thread for this issue.  
```Test Cases/eb_login FAILED.
Reason:
com.kms.katalon.core.exception.StepFailedException: Unable to click on object 'Object Repository/Page_Efendibey Admin/span_'
 at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.ClickKeyword.click(ClickKeyword.groovy:86)
 Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <span class="mat-select-placeholder ng-tns-c12-6 ng-star-inserted">...</span> is not clickable at point (487, 359). Other element would receive the click

Comment: Could you try to use other identifiers? Could you post details of object?

Comment: Object Details here: //input[@id='deliveryDate']

Comment: Could you try to use other identifiers? I m not sure which & how to use other identifier for the date issue. I used Cropath Chrome plugin to get the xpath. After using the xpath the date gets selected but does not auto-close hence the flow terminates / freezes at date identifier.

Comment: @Ashar : I updated my answer with identifiers for your site.